# effective calculate method for RCPSP(resource constrained project scheduling problem)

Tags: c++, algorithm, job-scheduling

The problem I am solving is scheduling tasks from limited resources.

The way I thought about it is to use a two-dimensional array to identify resources.

I wonder how I can calculate efficiently because the operation speed is too long.

Using a binary tree is likely to be difficult. After calculation, there is a process of randomly exchanging indexes for the search process.

For example)

Factory's capacity : 4

A(2,2)  B(3,2) C(1,1)                  \\\\task(processing time , required area)

Schedule : A-B-C      ,1 means that there is space left, and 0 means that there is no space.

A task can only be allocated if the space required is continuously present.

The x-axis represents time and the y-axis represents capacity.

1 1 1 ...      ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ  1 1 1    ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ 0 0 0 1  ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ   0 0 0 1

1 1 1 ...      ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ  1 1 1   ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ 0 0 0 1  ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ    0 0 0 1

1 1 1 ...     ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ  0 0 1   ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ 0 0 1 1  ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ     0 0 1 1

1 1 1 ...     ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ  0 0 1  ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ 0 0 1 1 ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ      0 0  0 1

Answer (score 0):

The good new is your problem looks very similar to well known [Job shop scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) problem. The bad new is `Job shop scheduling` is NP-hard.

Comment: Yes, I know. However, because the job shop does not consider space constraints, can simply calculate the makespan.

Comment: Typically, a job shop assumes that only one job is possible on one machine. But in the case of my problem, I can do many things at the same time